# Emulate Vim's ScrollBind Behavior in Intellij IDEA

Tags: vim, intellij-idea

I've really come to rely on Vim's ScrollBind functionality when viewing in 'Split Modes' ... However, It would really be great if that was available in Intellij IDEA ... I've searched but haven't had much luck ... Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diff view is a workaround, but there is no direct equivalent for this feature when using the split editors. Consider voting for the [related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-1046).

Comment: Thanks CC ... I'll do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

'[Compare Two Files](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/comparing-files.html)' seems to do the job ...